# How to delete any lines containing numbers?

Tags: unix, sed

I need to delete all lines that contain numbers so I have only words left.

```
sed -i '/^[[:digit:]]*$/d' filename.TXT
```

Not sure if sed works.

Comment: That regular expression will match lines that contain *only* numbers (and empty lines); if you want to delete any line that contains at least a number, drop the `^` and `$`, and use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 2):

This sed will delete all lines containing any number:

```
sed '/[0-9]/d' filename.txt
```

awk solution

```
awk '!/[0-9]/' filename.txt
```

grep solution

```
grep -v '[0-9]' filename.txt
```

Comment: The exact meaning of `[0-9]` depends on the locale and can be something other than `[0123456789]` – `[[:digit:]]`is usually the better, locale-safe choice.

Comment: Thanks, here are some details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d